# Como obtener los datos de un usuario logeado para hacer su perfil?

Tags: php, web, login

Tengo solamente ese problema, como puedo hacerle para que agarre el usuario.

Esto es lo que tengo en login.php

```
<form method="POST" action ="revisar.php" target="_top"/>
<table align="center">
 <tr>
      <td>
        Usuario
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="name" name="Usuarios"/>
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>
        Contraseña
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="Contrasena"/>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en revisar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$Usuarios = $_POST['Usuarios'];
$Contrasena = $_POST['Contrasena'];
$Usuarios = stripcslashes($Usuarios);
$Contrasena = stripcslashes($Contrasena);
$Usuarios = mysql_real_escape_string($Usuarios);
$Contrasena = mysql_real_escape_string($Contrasena);

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("usuarios");

$Contrasena = md5($Contrasena);
$result = mysql_query("select * from registro where Usuarios = '$Usuarios'") 
or die(" ERROR ".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$res =  "Error en usuario y/o contraseña!";
if($row['Usuarios']){ 
if($row['Contrasena'] == $Contrasena){
    $res = '';
    $_SESSION['Cargo']=$row['Cargo'];
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
    header("Location: index.php");
}
}
echo $res;
?>
```

Como se podría hacer el perfil teniendo éste código?

Comment: Hola, lamentablemente no se entiende muy bien que necesitas hacer. Intenta explicar mejor el resultado que esperas obtener y comparte lo que has intentado para hacerlo.

Comment: Solamente que la página de perfil pueda mostrar los datos del usuario que está activo. Como su nombre, apellido y nombre de usuario.

Comment: Entonces solo necesitas mostrarlos de donde sea que los estés guardando. ¿Dónde los estás guardando y cuál es el código de la página de perfil que tienes hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp) y acceder a ella desde cualquier página de tu dominio. La cookie se mantendrá activa el tiempo que determines, de manera que el usuario no tenga que volver a llevarse cada vez que entre.

```
if($row['Usuarios'] && $row['Contrasena'] == $Contrasena){
        $res = '';
        $Cargo=$row['Cargo'];
        $id=$row['id'];

        //Cookie que dura un año
        setcookie('miwebcookie',$cargo.':'.$id,time()+3600*24*365);
        // Si quieres que la cookie expire al acabar la sesión no añadas el último término, que es el tiempo de duración

        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Y en `index.php` compruebas que existe la cookie

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['miwebcookie']) {
 //Hay cookie de usuario hago lo que corresponda
 // aquí accedo a los valores almacenados en la cookie (segundo parámetro)
 $cookie_valor = $_COOKIE['miwebcookie']; 
} else { // no hay cookie le llevo a registro o lo que corresponda
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente cuando rescates los datos de la BD, guarda los datos en las variables de $_SESSION.

Por ejemplo:

```
if($row['Contrasena'] == $Contrasena){
    $res = '';
    $_SESSION['Cargo']=$row['Cargo'];
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

En esa parte del código, donde has declarado las variables $_SESSION para el Cargo y la ID, crea también variables para los datos personales:

```
$_SESSION['Nombre'] = $row['NombreEnLaBD'];
$_SESSION['Apellidos'] = $row['ApellidosenlaBD'];
$_SESSION['Genero'] = $row['GeneroenlaBD'];
```

Y todo lo que necesites guardar. Después, en la página de su perfil, solo tienes que hacer el echo de la variable $_SESSION y ya esta.

```
echo $_SESSION['Nombre'];
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda. Ese código lo tengo que meter en la página de perfil o en otro documento .php?